# Loading Bootstrap Wysiwyg editor content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Found this [Save and Load Bootstrap Wysiwyg editor content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875932/save-and-load-bootstrap-wysiwyg-editor-content). but loading does not work as suggested.

Created http://jsfiddle.net/vNPAJ/28/

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {            
            $("#t1").wysihtml5();
            $("#b1").click(function () {
                $("#t2").val($("#t1").val());                
            });
            $("#b2").click(function () {
                $("#t1").val($("#t2").val());
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
<textarea style="width:570px" id="t1">Test <b>Data</b></textarea><br /><br />
<textarea id="t2"style="width:570px"></textarea><br /> <br />
<button class="btn-primary" id="b1" type="button">Get</button>
<button class="btn-primary" id="b2" type="button">Set</button>
```

Get is working fine.

On clicking set button I want to fill editor with source from 2nd textarea.

Not sure how to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon researching your issue. It seems that you need to use a hack in order to populate the value in `wysihtml5()` since it includes iframe

Try doing this, i added a line in `#bt2` that set value to `#t1`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {            
            $("#t1").wysihtml5();
            $("#b1").on('click',function () {
                $("#t2").val($("#t1").val());                
            });
            $("#b2").on('click',function () {

                $("#t1").parent('body').find('iframe').contents().find('.wysihtml5-editor').html('I changed!');
            });
        });
```